# Elastic DSL: Aggregate and order by keys as numeric

Tags: querydsl, elasticsearch

In my dataset, where  duration field is string, I am trying to find aggregation count on duration in the way below:

```
"aggs": {
    "duration": {
      "terms": {
            "script": "Math.ceil(doc[\"duration\"].value as double)",
            "order" : { "_term" : "asc"}
          }
    }
  }
```

This returns result as :

```
"buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "1.0",
        "doc_count" : 4561
      }, {
        "key" : "10.0",
        "doc_count" : 117
      }, {
        "key" : "2.0",
        "doc_count" : 6004
      } ]
```

**Problem**: I want to order based on the numeric value of keys. Based on the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) I could not find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see are three possibilities:

A. Index your `duration`field as a number type, i.e. `integer`, `double` or whatever makes sense for your values

B. If you don't have too many different values for `duration` (AND if your durations are natural numbers) you could also use a [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) specifying all ranges (1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, etc)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "durations": {
      "range": {
        "script": "Math.ceil(doc.duration.value as double)",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 1
          },
          {
            "from": 1,
            "to": 2
          },
          {
            "from": 2,
            "to": 3
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

C. Use a [avg metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) sub-aggregation in order to infer the numeric value of the `duration` and use that value to sort the top aggregation.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "duration": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "Math.ceil(doc[\"duration\"].value as double)",
        "order": {
          "avgduration": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avgduration": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "doc.duration.value as double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, can you tell which option you chose? Thanks!

Comment: I cant change my mapping now. And i need absolute value in the key. Soi chose application level sorting for this issue.